# Magento 2 Share cart between multiwebsites

Tags: magento2, multi-website

I have two websites like abc.com and bcd.com. Each website have seperate store.
Now i want to share the cart items between both the websites. That means now customer login from abc.com and added one product to cart and logout from abc.com. And same customer login from bcd.com and i want to show product in cart which was added from abc.com.

Comment: impossible. carts are attached to a website/store. you will have to modify a lot in the magento-core

Comment: Hi Philipp Sander , Thank you for quick reply. You told lot of Magento core-files to change. Do you have any idea  steps need to follow to implement this functionality and How. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can control cart sharing from admin as well.

Go to :

```
Stores -> Customers -> Customer Configuration tab
```

Find the `Account Sharing Options` section.

Set the `Share Customer Accounts` setting to `Global`

Save the configuration

Comment: Hi Amit Naraniwal, Already set  customer configuration  to global. Still i am unable to share the cart items. I am able to login website 1 customer in  website2 without creating customer in website2. But i need cart items which are already added in website , those items i need to show in website2 also.

Comment: cart item sharing between websites is not possible by design (in default magento). If you want to share carts between a multi store setup the easiest way would be to divide them on store group level and not on website level.